# ADT Eclipse Dependency Error

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

Trying to install ADT Plugin in newly unzipped eclipse but getting this issue, any idea??

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android DDMS 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.0.20100617-0521]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.0.I20100603-1100]
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of eclipse you are using now ? 
I think latest adt need at least 3.6.2 eclipse.